# Today Widget unable to load with a specific line of code

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I've added a Today extension to my app and it all works fine until a specific line of code is compiled. NB: compiled, *not* executed!

My `TodayViewController` is:

```
class StoredDoses {
 func getDoses(doses: inout [Dose]) {
  if let userD = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.btv.mySuite") {
   if let dosesData = userD.object(forKey: "doses_key") {
    do {
     // -----------------------------------------------
     // Comment the line below out and the widget works
     doses = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Dose].self, from: dosesData as! Data)
     // -----------------------------------------------
    } catch {
      print ("ERROR")
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {

 @IBOutlet weak var aText: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var bText: UILabel!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
  }

 func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: (@escaping (NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
  // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

  // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResult.Failed
  // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResult.NoData
  // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResult.NewData

  //Just for development stage - not real, final code
  let form = DateFormatter()
  form.timeStyle = .short
  aText.text = form.string(from: Date())

  completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.newData)
 }
}
```

So, the above code isn't well written, but it's what I've used to finally narrow down the cause of the unloading widget. The array of `Doses` is a custom, codable class, but if I try to get an array of `String` then it's the same. The `StoredDoses` code is included in the main app and doesn't cause any problems.

Just to re-iterate: I'm not trying to execute any method in the `StoredDoses` class. I don't even have an instance of it in the widget. When the `doses = ...` line is merely commented out then the widget loads and the `aText` label in the widget appears with the current time in it.

Comment: Is there a compiler warning or error message?

Comment: Nope, not a thing. Compiled just fine and the app works but go to the widget and it reports ‘unable to load’

Comment: Can you attach to the widget process to get debug messages?

Comment: Ah. Now you’re asking. I’ve never done that before. I’ll get back to you on that.

Comment: I only learned about it recently - you can run your app and attach to the widget process from the menu in XCode, or you can click on the run menu and choose the extension itself rather than the app.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll give it a go.

Comment: Near the bottom of XCode’s `debug` menu is the option to attach to a process. Look for your Today widget / extension in the list. This should give you debug messages the same as you get for the app and should let you know where the problem lies in that line. I suspect it might be to do with the force cast `as! Data`.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now - I only know just enough to be dangerous. I've tried all that and there are absolutely no console messages for the widget.

Comment: Right. *sigh*. It appears to have been an IB issue. Somehow it was compiling with an older version of one of the `UILabel` names. However I only found that out after I explored @Chris comment about the `as! Data`. I re-wrote to first get the `Data` so adding `if let unwrappedData = [dosesData] as? Data...`. Once this was done then finally there was a fatal exception and the console showed the problem label name! Does that mean you sort of answered my question, @Chris....? :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! I think you solved the problem yourself, I only offered debugging help. It might be useful to post what you did as an answer in case it helps someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so thanks to @Chris' apparently unconnected advise I got it sorted!

It appears to have been an Interface Builder issue: somehow it had retained the original name of the `UILabel` that was auto-created when I added the Today extension in Xcode. At some point, after connecting an `IBOutlet` to the label with "Hello World" in it, I'd renamed it to something slightly more relevant but hadn't unconnected it before over-typing the new name in the `TodayViewController`.

The console didn't throw up any problems and at times seemed to work, but when the line with

`try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Dose].self, from: dosesData as! Data)`

was present then it stopped working without any console messages.

I only found that out after I explored @Chris comment about the `as! Data`. I re-wrote to first get the Data:

```
if let userD = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.btv.mySuite") {
  if let dosesData = userD.object(forKey: "doses_key") {
     if let unwrappedData = dosesData as? Data {
       do {
           doses = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([SplitDose].self, from: unwrappedData)
       } catch {
         doses.removeAll()
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Once this was compiled (remember, it's still not being executed - this is just sitting there waiting to be used) the console threw up a message and the app crashed out showing the old `UILabel` name as `not key-compliant`. Reconnecting the `UILabel` in IB fixed everything and I could compile the original code....

This probably deserves a Radar entry but right now I don't want to waste another day re-creating (if at all possible) this problem!

Comment: Good answer! :)